# Как вызвать один и тот же обработчик в разных слушателях

Tags: java, swing, события, awt

Имеется на форме одна кнопка (result), которая выполняет определенные вычисления при помощи слушателя `result.addActionListener(new resultEventListener ())`, как вызвать те же самые вычисления только при нажатии на энтер? К этой же кнопке добавлен слушатель `result.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapterOut())`, где в keyPressed если `e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` нужно выполнить те же вычисления, что и в addActionListener. Вот код

```
package calc2;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Gui extends JFrame {
    private JButton sum = new JButton(" + ");
    private JButton minus = new JButton(" - ");
    private JButton result = new JButton(" = "); 
    private JButton clear = new JButton("CE");  //очистка всего и присваивание false
    private JTextField out = new JTextField(10);  //сюда вводим значения
    private JLabel eventLabel = new JLabel();   //сюда выводим результат
    private JLabel eventLabel2 = new JLabel();  //сюда выводим действие +, - и.т.д.


     boolean press;
     boolean press2;
     boolean focus = false;
     int D1;
     int D2;
     int D3;
     int i=0;   //для плюса, чтобы работала логика +=
     int K=0;   //для минуса, чтобы работала логика -=
     boolean m = false;   //для минуса, чтобы выводить D1 (Условие К и m =0)
     int res=0;             //переменная чтобы ложить результат вычислений после нажатия на равно и использования его дальше
     boolean presssum=false;  //для идентификации нажатия равно



public Gui(){    //конструктор, который передает в JFrame название формы, положение и закрытие формы и ее наполнение
    super("Calculator");

    this.setBounds(500, 500, 300, 200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   Container cont = this.getContentPane(); //Экземпляр cont. Форма в которую можем помещать элементы
   cont.setLayout(null); //говорим что не будем использовать layout менеджер


   cont.add(result);
   result.addActionListener(new resultEventListener ());
   result.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapterOut());
   result.setBounds(125, 30, 50, 50);


}

class resultEventListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

    if (press == true){
        D2 = Integer.parseInt(out.getText());
        D3=K-D2;
    out.setText(null);
    eventLabel.setText(String.valueOf(D3));        
    press=false;
    sum.setEnabled(true);
    minus.setEnabled(true);

    res=D3; //для переноса в метод minusEventListener
    eventLabel2.setText(null);
    presssum=true;
     } else     
   if (press2 == true) {
        D2 = Integer.parseInt(out.getText());
        D3=i+D2;
    out.setText(null);
    eventLabel.setText(String.valueOf(D3)); 
    press2=false;  

    res=D3;     //для переноса в метод sumEventListener
    eventLabel2.setText(null);
    presssum=true; sum.setEnabled(true);
    minus.setEnabled(true);
    };
    }}




public class KeyAdapterOut implements KeyListener{

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      
} 
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 

 }

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {      //Вызванный, когда клавиша была нажата

  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {  
**//вот тут нужно выполнить то, что выполняется в resultEventListener**
}


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вынести код слушателя в отдельный метод, и вызывать этот метод из разных слушателей.

```
public class KeyAdapterOut extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            action();
        }
    }
}

class resultEventListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        action();
    }
}

private void action(){
    if (press == true){
        D2 = Integer.parseInt(out.getText());
        D3=K-D2;
        out.setText(null);
        eventLabel.setText(String.valueOf(D3));
        press=false;
        sum.setEnabled(true);
        minus.setEnabled(true);

        res=D3; //для переноса в метод minusEventListener
        eventLabel2.setText(null);
        presssum=true;
    } else
    if (press2 == true) {
        D2 = Integer.parseInt(out.getText());
        D3=i+D2;
        out.setText(null);
        eventLabel.setText(String.valueOf(D3));
        press2=false;

        res=D3;     //для переноса в метод sumEventListener
        eventLabel2.setText(null);
        presssum=true; sum.setEnabled(true);
        minus.setEnabled(true);
    };
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код, что бы ваш ответ не удалили